How to show the next session date depending on current date?
On my html website, I would like to show the date of the next lecture depending on the current data.
Let's say, the following dates exist:
Calender week 42 of 2024: October 14, 2024
Calender week 43 of 2024: October 21, 2024
Calender week 3 of 2025: January 14, 2025
I added the following code to my html-file but that does not work.
Please note that I am completely new to this.
 <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function getDateWeek(date) {
        const currentDate = 
            (typeof date === 'object') ? date : new Date();
        const januaryFirst = 
            new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
        const daysToNextMonday = 
            (januaryFirst.getDay() === 1) ? 0 : 
            (7 - januaryFirst.getDay()) % 7;
        const nextMonday = 
            new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 
            januaryFirst.getDate() + daysToNextMonday);
     
        return (currentDate < nextMonday) ? 52 : 
        (currentDate > nextMonday ? Math.ceil(
        (currentDate - nextMonday) / (24 * 3600 * 1000) / 7) : 1);
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const weekNumber = getDateWeek();
    let nextSession;
    switch (weekNumber) {
        case weekNumber <= 42:
          nextSession = "October 14, 2024";
          break;
        case weekNumber > 42 & weekNumber <= 43:
          nextSession = "October 21, 2024";
          break;
        case weekNumber > 43:
        nextSession = "January 14, 2025";
        break;
}
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Nächster Termin: " + nextSession;
      </script>


You are on the right track a bit but some key issues which I notice are stated below
Issues

Few key things- I could pinpoint is how you are using switch statements, switch statements don't work with conditions such as you have provided, if/else would suffice you only use switch if you have a defined case like switch to case 1 or 2 etc.
When to use switch cases; You can use it, if you have a simple option and you want to make reference to it multiple times.
Such as

let selected_option = 2
switch (selected_option) {
  case 1:
    console.log('This item is not available');
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log('This item is available');
    break;
}


Your use of bitwise operator & instead of logical &&(and): You should use &&

You need to able to tell, how to calculate a week's number, given year of interest.


Having said that , here is how to go about solving it, you might need to modify according to your preference but this holds true for all cases anyways. I have made the lectureDates an array of objects, so you can define what you want, because I don't know how frequent they are. so I provided an array for you to modify instead.
Here is a code snippet to guide you and I also modified your code a bit


const lectureDates = [
  { week: 42, date: "October 14, 2024" },
  { week: 43, date: "October 21, 2024" },
  { week: 3, date: "January 14, 2025" },
];

function getWeekNumber(date) {
  const currentDate = date || new Date();
  const januaryFirst = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  const daysToNextMonday =
    januaryFirst.getDay() === 1 ? 0 : (7 - januaryFirst.getDay() + 1) % 7;
  const nextMonday = new Date(
    currentDate.getFullYear(),
    0,
    januaryFirst.getDate() + daysToNextMonday
  );
  const weekNumber =
    Math.ceil((currentDate - nextMonday) / (24 * 3600 * 1000) / 7) + 1;
  return weekNumber;
}

function getNextLectureDate(
  lectureDay,
  lectureStartHour,
  lectureEndHour,
  date
) {
  const currentDate = date || new Date();
  const currentWeek = getWeekNumber(currentDate);
  const currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
  const currentTime = currentDate.getHours() * 60 + currentDate.getMinutes();
  const lectureStartTime = lectureStartHour * 60;
  const lectureEndTime = lectureEndHour * 60;

  let nextSession = "No lectures today";

  for (const lecture of lectureDates) {
    const lectureDate = new Date(lecture.date);
    lectureDate.setHours(lectureEndHour, 0, 0, 0);

    if (currentDate.getTime() <= lectureDate.getTime()) {
      if (currentDate.toDateString() === lectureDate.toDateString()) {
        if (currentTime <= lectureEndTime) {
          nextSession = lecture.date;
          break;
        }
      } else {
        nextSession = lecture.date;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(
    currentWeek,
    currentDay,
    lectureStartTime / 60,
    lectureEndTime / 60
  );
  return nextSession;
}

const lectureDay = 1; // Monday
const lectureStartHour = 15; // 3 PM
const lectureEndHour = 17; // 5 PM

console.log(getNextLectureDate(lectureDay, lectureStartHour, lectureEndHour));
console.log(
  getNextLectureDate(
    lectureDay,
    lectureStartHour,
    lectureEndHour,
    new Date("2024-10-21T14:30:00")
  )
);




For example, on Tuesday to Sunday in week 42, the next lecture is still shown to be "October 14, 2024". But is should be "October 21, 2024", that is the date of week 43.

are you requesting the date to be dynamic, what I can do is to provide you a way to alter the date in the array I provided. The array I provided is for you to specify which date of lectures you want not the time, let me change it let us see what happens? so for lectureDates just specify what you want there and it would do the calculation based on the time you want? I have hardcoded the date as a testing example so you would need to change it so suit your times. I have updated the code anyways. Let us see what happens. Also note that "October 21, 2024", is in the future I am working with date

By the way: Here, a week starts on Monday. So I guess I have to modify the function getWeekNumber? Probably just return weekNumber -1; - - The rest of your code is exactly what I wanted to have, thanks a lot!!

@Rhjg No worries I have modified the code so it starts from 1 like you suggested apologies occupational hazard, I have also added some test cases so you can see if it meets your requirements. I am glad I could help

Can it be possible that this part is not working?
if (
lectureDate.week > currentWeek ||
(lectureDate.week === currentWeek && isPastLectureTime)
) {
nextSession = lectureDate.date;
break; // Stop loop after finding the first upcoming date
Because the date is not incremented, isn't it`?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
